# open_basedir restriction error with OAuth CakePHP plugin

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to implement the OAuth CakePHP plugin here: https://github.com/seddonmedia/cakephp-oauth-server

Everything seems to be working as expected until when the user accepts the app to be authorized with the API and the following error happens:

```
Warning (2): file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/dev/urandom) is not within the allowed path(s): (/nfs:/tmp:/usr/local:/etc/apache2/gs-bin) [APP/Plugin/OAuth/Vendor/oauth2-php/lib/OAuth2.php, line 1064]
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /html/thirdparty/lib/Cake/Utility/Debugger.php:805) [APP/Plugin/OAuth/Vendor/oauth2-php/lib/OAuth2.php, line 945]
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /html/thirdparty/lib/Cake/Utility/Debugger.php:805) [APP/Plugin/OAuth/Vendor/oauth2-php/lib/OAuth2.php, line 946]
```

The method that calls before the error is below.

And it happens on the post when the user clicks accept.

public function authorize () {

```
if (!$this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'login', '?' => $this->request->query));
}

if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->validateRequest();

    $userId = $this->Auth->user('id');

    if ($this->Session->check('OAuth.logout')) {
        $this->Auth->logout();
        $this->Session->delete('OAuth.logout');
    }

    //Did they accept the form? Adjust accordingly
    $accepted = $this->request->data['accept'] == 'Yep';
    try {
        $this->OAuth->finishClientAuthorization($accepted, $userId, $this->request->data['Authorize']);
    } catch (OAuth2RedirectException $e) {
        $e->sendHttpResponse();
    }
}

// Clickjacking prevention (supported by IE8+, FF3.6.9+, Opera10.5+, Safari4+, Chrome 4.1.249.1042+)
$this->response->header('X-Frame-Options: DENY');

if ($this->Session->check('OAuth.params')) {
        $OAuthParams = $this->Session->read('OAuth.params');
        $this->Session->delete('OAuth.params');
} else {
    try {
        $OAuthParams =  $this->OAuth->getAuthorizeParams();
    } catch (Exception $e){
        $e->sendHttpResponse();
    }
}
$this->set(compact('OAuthParams'));
```

}

Not sure what the problem is... Can anyone offer any advice on what the issue is or how I could investigate further?

EDIT: Tried editing the code below based on comments:

```
protected function genAccessToken() {
    $tokenLen = 40;
    //if (file_exists('/dev/urandom')) { // Get 100 bytes of random data
    if(mt_rand(0,99999999)) {
        $randomData = file_get_contents('/dev/urandom', false, null, 0, 100) . uniqid(mt_rand(), true);
    } else {
        $randomData = mt_rand() . mt_rand() . mt_rand() . mt_rand() . microtime(true) . uniqid(mt_rand(), true);
    }
    return substr(hash('sha512', $randomData), 0, $tokenLen);
}
```

Comment: check file: APP/Plugin/OAuth/Vendor/oauth2-php/lib/OAuth2.php on line 1064 and replace the `file_get_contents("/dev/urandom")` with `mt_rand(0,99999999);` That way you dont have to access /dev/urandom to get a random number.

Comment: Tried that but just get more errors. And should I be editing the Vendor? Thought this stuff was tried and tested. Check my OP for a snippet of the code I have changed.

Comment: You can ask your host to include /dev/urandom to your open_basedir, that will solve it.

Comment: And if I can't? What would be the correct fix for that function above? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the function with. This way you dont need access to /dev/urandom

```
protected function genAccessToken() {
    $tokenLen = 40;
    //if (file_exists('/dev/urandom')) { // Get 100 bytes of random data

        $randomData = mt_rand() . mt_rand() . mt_rand() . mt_rand() . microtime(true) . uniqid(mt_rand(), true);

    return substr(hash('sha512', $randomData), 0, $tokenLen);
}
```

Comment: Haha yeah figured it out myself just then. But would never have looked at that line unless you had commented above. Thanks for the help ;)